# Change Text Size to Fit Button

Tags: vb.net, text-size

I have a bunch of buttons that are populated with multi-lines. Once they are populated I want to change the size of the text so that you can see all the text and none is cut off.

Because the amount of text changes I can't use a set Textsize

How can I tell if the button is showing all the text?

Comment: You could set the button to `AutoSize = true` but that means the button size itself will change. I don't think there's a way to know if the text is "too long" for the button, unless you know how long it can get, and just check the text's length and change the font size accordingly.

Comment: I don't want the button size to change, and the text length is constantly changing

Comment: The only thing I can think of, is to say "if the text is xx long, set the font size to #, else if ..." That's fairly ghetto, but like I said before, I don't know if you can programmatically tell if the text is being clipped.

Comment: Multiline text in a fixed, confined space means the font could get very small.  Why not use a ToolTip to show the full text and write some code to clip the actual text to a certain sensible length?

Comment: you can use MeasureString to figure out what font size to use for a certain width button. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx